# Sails does not clear cache without hard refresh

Tags: node.js, sails.js

My Sails application does not update javascript files in production.
I am starting sails on production:

> NODE_ENV=production forever start app.js

But when i open the website, i dont see any changes. Even if i restart the website. Changes applies only after hard-refresh with ctrl+F5, or manually clearing the cache.

But locally it works.

This is probably something with cache, that browser is not forced to update/clear the cache. How to solve that?

My tasks/config/sails-linker.js:

```
  grunt.config.set('sails-linker', {
    devJs: {
      options: {
        startTag: '<!--SCRIPTS-->',
        endTag: '<!--SCRIPTS END-->',
        fileTmpl: '<script src="%s?v='+ new Date().getTime() +'"></script>',
        appRoot: '.tmp/public'
      },
      files: {
        '.tmp/public/**/*.html': require('../pipeline').jsFilesToInject,
        'views/**/*.html': require('../pipeline').jsFilesToInject,
        'views/**/*.ejs': require('../pipeline').jsFilesToInject
      }
    },
```

because i am not using `sails lift` on production, i changed the grunt default  to this:

```
/tasks/register/default.js

module.exports = function (grunt) {


grunt.registerTask('default', [
    'compileAssets',
    'linkAssetsBuildProd',
    'watch',
    'concat',
    'uglify',
    'cssmin',
    'sails-linker:prodJs',
    'sails-linker:prodJsJade',
  ]);
};
```

I have no idea where to look next.

Comment: I would advise you to use pm2 instead. It is much better and complete! Second, grunt tasks towards production mode does not watch for changes in the JS/CSS file, because it minify everything BEFORE production. To see changes live in your code/style, you should use `sails lift` normally. Your pipeline of tasks is wrong because Grunt is compacting/uglyfying before watching...

Comment: Thanks. I changed grunt  and updated the question. This didnt help me achieve what i wanted - my changes still does not apply without hard-refresh.

Comment: I have also instlaled and used pm2 - still nothing changes.

Comment: Can you be a bit clearer? Is the "required hard reload" your only concern, or is there something else? Is sails not updating in some other way (in prod or not, local machine or not)? I had a tough struggle with grunt and prod mode, so I may have some insights once I get your problem.

Comment: Hm. Its like: when i update my server, the client is not getting updated assets. If i click f5, nothing changes even after 10 times. if i click ctrl+f5, only then i can see my updated assets. Locally i have updated assets after simple f5. I have tried many different ways so far, but unsuccessfully. I dont know exactly where the roots are.. why the cache is not updated on production..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have fixed it now like this:

on tasks/config/sails-linker.js added this:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {

  var time = new Date().getTime();

  grunt.config.set('sails-linker', {
```

and then changed there every line from

```
fileTmpl: '<script src="%s"></script>'
```

to

```
fileTmpl: '<script src="%s?v='+ time +'"></script>'
```

And on production server on every update with assets i run

```
sails www --prod
```

And then

```
NODE_ENV=production pm2 start app.js
```

This works. At least. This generates everytime new minified javascript file with new version, and browser reloads then.

Comment: Don't forget to replace also the css link template: `'<link rel="stylesheet" href="%s">'` with `'<link rel="stylesheet" href="%s?v=' + time + '">'`.

Comment: Thanks, but my project uses no css :)